# PHP getallheaders giving different header output on Dev and Production

Tags: php, web-services, apache, header

I'll try not to be confusing but I am literally perplexed over this situation.

I am using `getallheaders()` for one of my application to get all the header information. It is being used in a following way :-

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(getallheaders()); 
?>
```

The problem now is that it provides different output for my dev and production server, which is why my application doesn't work on Production yet it works on Dev. I am trying my best to find the reason for it but still to no avail.

### Here is the output of Dev (Correct one)

```
\::<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">

                {"accept":"text\/html,application\/xhtml+xml,application\/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-language":"en-us",
    "connection":"close",
    "content-length":"0",
    "host":"production-host",
    "iv-user":"cn=First_Name%20Last_Name,
    ou=NYC,
    ou=NorthAmerica,
    o=Company_Name",
    "user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit\/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile\/10B141",
    "via":"HTTP\/1.1 .company_name.com:80",
    "**location_office_code" :"XYZ"**,
    "iv_server_name":"default-webseald-na-pcompanyname.intranet.company_name.com",
    "vendorid":"a_number",
    "person_id":"a_number",
    **"position_category":"NOT_FOUND","position_code":"NOT_FOUND",
    "region_code":"North%20America",
    "mail":"Email-Address"**,
    "x-forwarded-for":"IP_Address",
    "Cookie":"s_nr=1324338612-New"}</pre></body></html>


[INFO] :   strJsonContent information:

{"accept":"text\/html,application\/xhtml+xml,
application\/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8",
"accept-language":"en-us",
"connection":"close",
"content-length":"0",
"host":"host_name",
"iv-user":"cn=FIRST_NAME%20LAST_NAME,
ou=NYC,
ou=NorthAmerica,
o=COMPANY_NAME",
"user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit\/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile\/10B141",
"via":"HTTP\/1.1 .comapny_name:80",
"location_office_code":"XYZ",
"iv_server_name":"default-webseald-na-comapny_name.com",
"vendorid":"a-number",
"person_id":"a-number",
"position_category":"NOT_FOUND",
"position_code":"NOT_FOUND",
"region_code":"North%20America",
"mail":"EMAIL_ADDRESS",
"x-forwarded-for":"IP_ADDRESS",
"Cookie":"s_nr=1324338612-New"
}
```

### Output of Production (Missing position_category, position_code, region_code, **mail**)

```
\::<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">

{"accept":"text\/html,application\/xhtml+xml,application\/xml;q=0.9,
*\/*;q=0.8",
"accept-language":"en-us",
"connection":"close",
"content-length":"0",
"host":"production-host",
"iv-user":"cn=First_Name%20Last_Name,
ou=NYC,
ou=NorthAmerica,
o=Company_Name",
"user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit\/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile\/10B141",
"via":"HTTP\/1.1 .company_name.com:80",
"iv_server_name":"default-webseald-na-pcompanyname.intranet.company_name.com",
"vendorid":"a_number",
"person_id":"a_number",
"x-forwarded-for":"IP_Address",
"Cookie":"s_nr=1324338612-New"}
</pre></body></html>


[INFO] :   strJsonContent information:
{"accept":"text\/html,application\/xhtml+xml,
application\/xml;q=0.9,
*\/*;q=0.8",
"accept-language":"en-us",
"connection":"close",
"content-length":"0",
"host":"host_name","iv-user":"cn=First_Name%20Last_Name,ou=NYC,ou=NorthAmerica,o=Company_Name",
"user-agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit\/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile\/10B141",
"via":"HTTP\/1.1 .company_name.com:80",
"iv_server_name":"default-webseald-na-pcompany_name.intranet.company_name.com",
"vendorid":"a_number",
"person_id":"a_number",
"x-forwarded-for":"IP_Address",
"Cookie":"s_nr=1324338612-New"}
    [INFO] :   responseAsJSON info:[object Object]
```

The things which are missing in the Production JSON are 
 - position_category
 - position_code
 - region_code
 - mail

The most important being is `mail`. Any idea why it's missing in the production? Where can I confirm that which values are being added in the Header and why can any value miss in this instance?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aaark! Can't you format this to make it more readable

Comment: All formatted. Hopefully, it's readable now. Please let me know if it's still not.

Comment: Any help ? Any suggestion? Any point that why headers on two different servers could be different? Thanks

Comment: @Steve I am facing the problem. Any solution Steve after 2 years?